Ivy files for avro 1.11.3
I have groovy/grapes dependency for avro(1.8.1), having three different folders:
avro: containing jar and ivy files
avro-parent: containing ivy files
avro-toplevel: containing ivy files

I want to update to 1.11.3.
I need to download these manually.
On maven repo I see jar for avro. But ivy files for toplevel and parent are not available.
Where can I find these files?
